# use dropzone with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropzone.js, formidable

I'm new to node.js, I was trying to make a file upload with drag and drop,

I first created a simple uploader (no drag and drop)

like this and it worked:

```
    var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      res.write('File uploaded');
      res.end();
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/ I can see the uploader and everything works.

Now I'm trying to use dropzone with drag and drop to upload instead of the simple upload with it but I can't figure out how to get it work

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      res.write('File uploaded');
      res.end();
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    res.write('<html><head><title>Dropzone </title><link href="dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><form method="post" action="/fileupload" id="uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="file" type="file" multiple /><button>Save</button></form><script src="dropzone.js"></script></body></html>');

    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Now when I run $ node my-file.js and I go to localhost:8080/ I see the normal uploader and not the dropzone uploader.

would appreciate if someone can help me to figure this out...

thanks in advance

Comment: You left the `action` attribute as `/` in your form

Comment: @Seblor thx, I fixed this mistake, but it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple upload appears as you need to include "dropzone" class in form for the styles to appear.

```
 res.write('<html><head><title>Dropzone </title><link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/3.8.4/css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><form method="post" action="/fileupload"   class="dropzone" id="uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data"><button>Save</button></form><script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/3.8.4/dropzone.js"></script></body></html>');
```

Comment: thx, I thought I did, but apparently I was doing it wrong!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML says:

> ```
> <script src="dropzone.js"></script>
> ```

But the logic of your server-side JavaScript says:

*If the URL is `/fileupload` then process the form data, otherwise send the browser an HTML page.*

So when the browser requests the JavaScript file, you give it an HTML page.

You need to write code which will deliver what the browser actually asks for.

(Tip: Your `else` should be code to generate a `404 Not Found` error page. Only generate actual content for URLs that are supposed to have actual content).